# How to remove a layout that have been inflated to the screen

Tags: java, android

I've created an in-app keyboard with two possible languages.

For each language there's a different layout (the root element of the layouts is merge).
I have a 'switch' Button in every layout for switching between the languages.

I've tried to set the layout that currently shown as 'GONE' and then add the second layout, but it doesn't work and instead of changing the layout, it just adding the second layout, and showing it with the second together.

Here is the Class that handles my keyboard.

The place that I handle the language switching is found at the Switch-Case inside the function onClick, case: 'R.id.button_switch':

```
public class MyKeyboard extends LinearLayout implements View.OnClickListener {

private SparseArray<String> keyValues = new SparseArray<>();
private InputConnection inputConnection;
private Boolean isEnglish;
private Context con;
private View keb;

public MyKeyboard(Context context) {
    this(context, null, 0);
}
public MyKeyboard(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context, attrs, 0);
}
public MyKeyboard(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    init(context, attrs);
}
private void init(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    con = context;
    //english(context);
    hebrew(context);
}

private void hebrew(Context context) {
    isEnglish = false;
    keb = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.heb_keyboard, this, true);

    findViewById(R.id.button_enter).setOnClickListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.button_delete).setOnClickListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.button_switch).setOnClickListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.button_alef).setOnClickListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.button_b).setOnClickListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.button_c).setOnClickListener(this);

    keyValues.put(R.id.button_alef, "א");
    keyValues.put(R.id.button_b, "b");
    keyValues.put(R.id.button_c, "c");
}

private void english(Context context) {
    isEnglish = true;
    keb = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.en_keyboard, this, true);

    findViewById(R.id.button_enter).setOnClickListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.button_delete).setOnClickListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.button_switch).setOnClickListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.button_a).setOnClickListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.button_b).setOnClickListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.button_c).setOnClickListener(this);

    keyValues.put(R.id.button_a, "a");
    keyValues.put(R.id.button_b, "b");
    keyValues.put(R.id.button_c, "c");
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    if (inputConnection == null)
        return;

    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.button_delete:
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(inputConnection.getSelectedText(0))) {
                inputConnection.deleteSurroundingText(1, 0);
            } else {
                inputConnection.commitText("", 1);
            }
            break;

        case R.id.button_enter:
            inputConnection.finishComposingText();
            this.setVisibility(INVISIBLE);
            break;

        case R.id.button_switch:
            if (isEnglish)
                hebrew(con);
            else
                english(con);
            break;

        default:
            inputConnection.commitText(keyValues.get(view.getId()), 1);
            break;
    }
}

public void setInputConnection(InputConnection ic) {
    inputConnection = ic;
}
}
```

I need to find how to remove the previews layout that were inflated before, and then add the other layout.

Comment: If you set visibility of a view to gone, and add another child to it's parent, must not be any problems.

Answer (score 0):

If problem with `setVisibility(GONE)` not fixed, you can use a `FrameLayout` and change the fragment of it this way:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.main_container, fragment, newTag).commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

> Try this

```
View view = inflate(mContext, R.layout.en_keyboard, this);
```